# Tagged pointer explanation in v8

Tags: pointers, v8

I was reading v8 internals and came across tagged pointer, i googled it but coudnt understood it clearly. Please can anyone explain me briefly what is it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer

Comment: I read that Wikipedia article, but coudn't understand it, it mentioned examples from objective-C

Comment: Ex. If you know that some value is always allocated on an address that is a multiple of a power of two, then you know that the lower few bits are always zero, and can store additional information in them.

Comment: ohkay, that's why Objects are 4-byte aligned, so that least significant digits which are zero can be used for some other purpose. Thanks alot.